# How can i acess with indentity server with multiple application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

after the user loggin in the site A, when him acces the site B, the allow page is showed up to the user allow the site B acces his profile, so after allow the site B access his profile, the site A will ask again for authorization.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I would advise you edit your question to provide either your relevant code or a description of how you are using the Identity Server, since I think at present the community does not have sufficient information to help you effectively. Thanks.

Comment: okay i will edit with relavant code thank you very much